# What do you call a person with a bachelor's degree?

Tags: undergraduate, titles, translations

I am a nutritionist in Mexico and I have a bachelor's degree.(I studied for four years at a university) In mexico my bussiness card says L.N. which means licenciada en Nutricion. I don't know how to translate that.

Comment: (I don't speak Spanish but) Licenced Nutritionist? Or BSc Nutrition?

Comment: In the U.S., by chance I am aware, that the B.S. or B.A. degree in nutrition/dietetics is legally distinct from licensure (state-by-state!) as "registered dietitian", for example. There is a separate examination and licensure process in Minnesota, for example. One can have one without the other, and one must be careful about not making legally-false claims. This is a little like the use of degree-titles in Germany, which is much more legally constrained than in the U.S. (in this case oppositely to the immediate question).

Comment: @Paul But "Licenciado" is not the Mexican Spanish equivalent of the degree you are describing. Most likely the degree is equivalent to either a BA or a BS, depending on specific details of the program.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, I certainly do not claim to really know the legal equivalents... I only wished to bring up the legal distinction (in MN, in the U.S.) between "license" and B.A. or B.S., since neither of the latter should be construed as "license". I'm not a great linguist, but I'm aware of the temptations to translate cognates to their cognate, which, after a few hundred years of drift, may say the wrong thing. Just trying to say "be careful"... :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways this can be translated. Some of which I have seen are:

- Licensed Dietitian
- Licensed Nutritionist
- Has a BSc in Nutrition

To my knowledge, there is no legal requirement in the United States that one of these be chosen over the others and in my personal opinion either of the first two are sufficient.
In the United Kingdom though, a Dietitian is someone who advises someone on their personal diet and diagnoses issues related to malnutrition while a Nutritionist gives general advice on how to eat.

Comment: @paul garret suggests there could be a difference between a state licensed nutritionist and having a BS in nutrition.